# Gmail canned response filter

Tags: gmail-filters

My colleagues keep sending work emails to my personal email (Gmail). Instead of repeatedly asking them to resend to my work account, I tried to set up the canned response function on Gmail. I enabled *Canned Response* in the lab settings, then created the canned response (“Please resend to work email xxx@xxxxx.xxx”), then set up the filter for my work domain `*@xxxx.xxx` and checked box to send my saved canned response when an email from that domain is received.

I tested it by sending an email from my work account to Gmail account, and nothing! Am I doing something wrong? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have made the filter correctly. Have you tried to add your explicit address as the sender, to test if that works? Remember canned response only work on new mail.

I have the opposite problem, people sending to my work mail, where I want it in my private mail.

I created a filter with `From: *@domain.xx` and checked `Forward it to:` my private mail. (Just have to add a forwarding address.)

This works for me, hope it may be a help to you.